# jQuery: $elem.attr is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, attributes, jquery-isotope

im using the following script in conjunction with isotope however i am coming up with the error  $elem.attr. I cant really see where im going wrong

```
var $container = $('.projects').isotope({
itemSelector: '.panel',
masonry: {
    columnWidth: 0
},
getSortData: {
    responsive: function($elem) {
        return parseInt($elem.attr('data-category-responsive'), 10);
    },
    ecommerce: function($elem) {
        return parseInt($elem.attr('data-category-ecommerce'), 10);
    },
    brochure: function($elem) {
        return parseInt($elem.attr('data-category-brochure'), 10);
    }
}
});
```

any help would be deeply appreciated thankyou

Comment: Should not be something like this `$(elem).attr();`?

Comment: Seems to be correct, what exactly is the error you're getting in the console.

Comment: TypeError: $elem.attr is not a function
 

return parseInt($elem.attr('data-category-responsive'), 10);

Comment: how is those methods called

Comment: @ArunPJohny - like this -> http://isotope.metafizzy.co/docs/options.html#getsortdata

Comment: Console log $elem in each function, you're probably using a key that does not match the markup.

Comment: doesnt seem to be flagging anything up

Comment: oh god dont worry its because id started to use the v2 of isotope to experiment with and forgot to switch back to the original which these functions relate to.